# font awesome icons not displaying in html

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

i have a contact form in html , i gave font awesome icons for the input fields, the oce is below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrap-input100">
      <input class="input100" type="number" name="pass" placeholder="Mobile Number">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf095;"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="wrap-input100">
      <input class="input100" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Query">
      <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf128;"></span>
     </div>
```

but the font awesome doesnt seem to work, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use font awesome icons, don't use `data-placeholder`. Font Awesome is a font that converts glyphs to icons. So, your fixed code would be:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrap-input100">
  <input class="input100" type="number" name="pass" placeholder="Mobile Number">
  <span class="focus-input100 fa">&#xf095;</span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100">
  <input class="input100" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Query">
  <span class="focus-input100 fa">&#xf128;</span>
</div>
```

Also, as a quick side note, most people prefer using the `<i>` tag for icons.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use font awesome in input placeholder,u can use this code.

```css
    input {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

   <div class="wrap-input100">
      <input class="input100" type="number" name="pass" placeholder="&#xf095; Mobile Number ">
     </div>

     <div class="wrap-input100">
      <input class="input100" type="text" name="question" placeholder="&#xf128; Your Query" >
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a `data-placeholder` when working with font-awesome.
You should instead use the font-awesome classes like below:

```html
<span class="focus-input100 fa fa-phone"></span>
<span class="focus-input100 fa fa-question"></span>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrap-input100">
    <input class="input100" type="number" name="pass" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    <span class="focus-input100 fa fa-phone"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100">
    <input class="input100" type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Query">
    <span class="focus-input100 fa fa-question"></span>
</div>
```